# Increment variable name using another variable

Tags: powershell

I am creating many variables that end with an incrementing number,

```
$var0 = "foo"
$var1 = "bar"
$var2 = "ack"
$var3 = "influenza"      # ran out of fillers
```

I want to check each of these variables for the one containing "ack". My thinking is to use a `for`, increment `$i`, and use `$i` at the end of each variable name.

```
for($i=0;$i -le 3;$i++) {
    if((Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly) -eq "ack") {
        "result at var$i"
    }
    else {
        $i
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way than `Get-Variable` to use `$i` as part of a variable name? Or is the point to use an array in this scenario?

Comment: `Elegance` tends to be a pretty subjective aspect. From a general perspective, you won't find many people who wouldn't use a container type here. Whether an array is the right choice, or a list of tuples, or a map -- that's another question which must be answered in accordance with the operations you require throughout the whole program and their respective semantics as well as execution time. After having taken that design decision, you'd choose a proper implementation.

Comment: "ran out?" try these: ( http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html ) I prefer `foo` `bar` `baz` and `bizizzle`

Comment: I think an array is much better suited to this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use an [array](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html) instead of using multiple variables.